# Vue.js—V-model in v-for current object

Tags: vue.js, v-for, v-model

Basically I would like when I create several pages to allow the v-model to take the input used and not all at once here is the code :

```
 <div id="app">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <p class="jumbotron"> Titre de la page <input type="text" v-model="titre" > 
  <button type="submit"  v-on:click="ajouter()">Ajouter</button> </p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row-5" v-for="(titre,index) in titres">
               
                    <p class="list-group-item" style="text-align: center;">
                        Titre de la page : {{ titre }}
                       <input type="text" value="" v-model="titremodify" ><br>
                        <button class="btn btn-dark" v- 
 on:click="supprimer()">Supprimer</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-dark" v- 
  on:click="modifier(index)">Modifier</button>
                    </p>
                </div>        
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nestea29950/L8foc7zd/4/

Comment: It's not clear from your code what the question is. Can you describe what is wrong with your code, and what is *should* do compared to what it does right now?

Comment: on jfiddle when I create several page example  page1 and page2 and I want to modify the v-model goes on the other input https://jsfiddle.net/nestea29950/L8foc7zd/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you need to to is to add `titre` before your definition(s).

**TEMPLATE:**

```
...
  <button @click="ajouter()">Ajouter</button>
...
  <div v-for="(titre,index) in titres" :key="titre.id">
    <input v-model="titre.titremodify">
  </div>
...
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
data() {
  return {
    titres: [{    //this is your first input
      id: 1,
    }]
    titremodify: "", 
  }
}

methods: {
  ajouter: function(){   
    this.titres.push({
      id: this.id +=1
    }); 
  },
}
```

For every `titres` in your `v-for` you create a `titre` with a unique `ID` (this will help you out in future matters). So you just have to reference on this like above.

This should solve your problem.